# Mysql on a remote sever: iptables - allow access only for the application server

Tags: mysql, iptables

I am migrating my MySQL Database to t new server on Ubuntu 14.04. It is working fine at the moment.
I am trying to set up the right iptables for both server (web application server and mysql server). 
I tried the following on my Mysql server but it seems I made a mistake (I want to make sure that only my application server can connect to my Mysql server):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove all rules
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Forbid all traffic
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow established connection
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Mysql
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s MysqlserverIP --sport 1024:65535 -d ApllicationserverIP --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s ApllicationserverIP --sport 3306 -d MysqlserverIP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur)
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Prevent Flood or Ddos
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT

# Limit port scan
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

I can use:

```
# Mysql
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d 95.142.162.62 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 95.142.162.62 --sport 3306 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But then anybod can connect to mysql and I want only my application server to be able to establish this connection.

I was trying to use this post to set up my iptables for the port 3306: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html

My iptables for my Applications server are:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove all rules
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X

# Forbid all traffic
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow established connection
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Mysql


# Allow FTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SMTP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

# Allow POP3
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT

# Allow POPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allow IMAP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

# Allow IMAPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur)
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Prevent Flood or Ddos
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
# Allow IMAP
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT

# Allow IMAPS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# NTP (horloge du serveur)
sudo iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# Prevent Flood or Ddos
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/second -j ACCEPT

# Limit port scan
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

I based port 3306 iptables on a @MadHatter post: [IPTables: Allow outgoing MySQL connections but not incoming connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/646432/iptables-allow-outgoing-mysql-connections-but-not-incoming-connections)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What does your firewall log say when it blocks the connection?

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I have to admin I do not find the correct log file. the kern.log is not showing iptables log.